# AWS - Modify the name of an SSM parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

It's possible to modify the name of an SSM parameter Store?

With `aws-cli`, The put-parameter command only allows me to modify the value and the type (`SecureString` or `String`).

Do I need to copy the SSM parameter value to create a new one with a different name?

Thank's in advance,

Comment: No. You must pet then delete the other path.

Comment: Probably obvious, but too late to edit so I'll add for posterity that I meant "put" not "pet".

Comment: yes I understood ^^